# Questions to limit groups (over free groups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, group-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

My questions refer to the following article (both refer to page 27):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10278.pdf

1. In the article we find the statement that for a non-abelian limit group $L$ we always find a sequence of **epimorphisms** to $F_2$ that converges to $L$. By definition of a (non-abelian) limit group we find -a priori- only a sequence of homomorphisms. Why can the homomorphisms (in this situation) always be chosen to be surjective? From the article *"An Introduction to Limit Groups" (Wilton)* I could find out that limit groups are fully residually free and because $L$ is not abelian it has to contain a free group of rank at least 2. So there exists an epimorphism from $L$ to $F_2$. But this does not answer why this convergent homomorphism can be chosen to be epimorphisms.
2. On page 27 of the article we have a sequence $g_n$ of epimorphisms from $F_l$ to $L$. The autors say that we can pass to a subsequence that converges into a Limit group $L_1$. Why can one choose such a subsequence? I think that the answer to that is not so difficult but I still do not have a real idea. Maybe one can again use that limit groups are fully residually free and can apply properties of fully residually free groups to get the statement.

Comment: Please use the LaTeX language here, I can't read it :)  You can use links to or screenshots of https://q.uiver.app  for limit diagrams.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question :)

Comment: Is (1) not simply because if $L$ is a limit group over any free group, then it is a limit group over every free group, and in particular over $F_2$?

Comment: Yes, but with this argument we only get that L is a limit group over $F_2$. So we get the existence of  a convergent sequence of homomorphisms. But why can this homomorphisms be chosen to be surjective? Because this is what Fujiwara and Sela say.